# Ionic nav main attribute. What does it do?

Tags: ionic3

I was looking at`<ion-nav>` that goes by the class name **Nav**:

- [API docs](https://ionicframework.com/docs/api/components/nav/Nav/)
- [Navigation in Component docs](https://ionicframework.com/docs/components/#navigation)
- [Source code](https://github.com/ionic-team/ionic/blob/master/src/components/nav/nav.ts)

I noticed there is a method called `initPane()`, that makes reference to an attribute **main**.

So I presume you can have this code:

```
<ion-nav main>
</ion-nav>
```

What is the significance of this?

I see no mention of it in the documentation.

How does it impact the behaviour of your app?

I'm wondering if it's some sort of mechanism to automate setting the RootPage.

Can someone please clarify?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Found it here [SplitPane](https://ionicframework.com/docs/api/components/split-pane/SplitPane/)

> Here, SplitPane will look for the element with the **main** attribute and
>   make that the central component on larger screens. The main component
>   can be any Ionic component (ion-nav or ion-tabs) except ion-menu.